# Изменение/удаление учетных записей из бинарного файла

Tags: c, файлы, binary

Написал функцию записи и вывода данных учетной записи(права, логин, пароль). Не могу понять как изменить/удалить эти данные при надобности, двигать как-то указатель внутри файла и пробелы записывать?

```
#define size 255
...

void add(void){
    char login[size],password[size],permis,tmp,tmpstr[size];
    printf("Введите логин\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(login);
    printf("Введите пароль\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(password);
    printf("Выберите тип учетной записи\n1)Администратор\n2)Пользователь\n");
    switch (permis=getch()){
        case '1':
            permis='a';
            break;
        case '2':
            permis='u';
            break;
        default:
            printf("Неверное значение\n");
            return;
    }
    if (!(data=fopen("data.bin", "ab"))){
        printf("Невозможно создать/открыть файл\n"); return;
    }
        fwrite(&permis,sizeof(permis),1,data);
        fwrite(&login,sizeof(login),1,data);
        fwrite(&password,sizeof(password),1,data);
    fclose(data);
    if (!(data=fopen("data.bin", "r"))){
        printf("Невозможно создать/открыть файл\n"); return;
    }
        while(fread(&tmp,sizeof(char),1,data) && tmp!=EOF){
            printf("perm %c\n", tmp);
            fread(&tmpstr,sizeof(tmpstr),1,data);
            printf("login %s\n", tmpstr);
            fread(&tmpstr,sizeof(tmpstr),1,data);
            printf("password %s\n", tmpstr);
        }
    fclose(data);
    return;
}
```

И еще, правильно ли я проверяю конец файла?

Comment: [Нет, не правильно](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html), сравнивать с `EOF` надо результат вызова `fread()` (для полной уверенности, чтобы отличить конец файла от ошибки потом можно вызвать `feof()` или `ferror()`) (я понимаю, что вы просто тренируетесь, но на всякий случай -- на практике текстовые форматы для подобных целей лучше бинарных)

Comment: @avp вот так? while(!(feof(data))){

Comment: Не совсем. `feof()` можно проверять **после** чтения (поскольку именно чтение меняет состояние файла) Т.е. напишите просто `while((nbytes = fread(&tmp,sizeof(char),1,data)) != EOF) { ...`